# SAP management console turned yellow; cannot log in SAP system anymore

Tags: sap-basis

I installed SAP netweaver 7.02 trail from scn.sap.com. Installed it with youtube tutorial. worked fine for few hours. Later When I switch on management console it turns green and then turns back to yellow in few seconds. I couldn't access with sapGUI from other user which I did before few hours. GUI's error message is "partner '127.0.0.1:sapdp00' not reached".

Comment: Which processes are breaking down? What else is in the logs?

Comment: @vwegert saw some database errors in log. Anyways now formatted the system. Now using some demo version. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

see SAP Note 2040644 - Secure Internal Server Communication

Make sure you have stopped all SAP services/deamons before starting the instance again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).